# Should we use this site or meta.stackexchange to discuss issues with moderator tools?

Tags: discussion

Should we use this site or meta.stackexchange to discuss issues with moderator tools?

Here the presumption is that the questions will be targeted and will not generally be challenged by non-moderators, etc.

Comment: This question seems to be focusing mainly in SE: http://moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/89/should-moderators-be-involved-in-chat-or-just-be-ready-to-take-action-if-needed (not every community has a chat for example)

Answer (score 30):

The point of this site is:

> This is a site for people building, administering, managing and cultivating digital communities.

So no, discussion of SE specific problems should still be asked on meta.stackexchange

Comment: Indeed. "What tools can be used to manage situation X?" is a solid question for this site. "How do I handle flags on my SE site?" belongs on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com). That sounds like a reasonable line to draw right from the start. (Assuming this site doesn't take a strict stance against tool recommendations, etc. This is just an example.)